# Recommended file hosting service

Tags: support

**I understand that sharing personal file host links shouldn't be endorsed**, but there are instances when this is mandatory.
The website hosting the file [in my question](https://superuser.com/questions/1153751/what-does-there-are-some-data-after-the-end-of-the-payload-data-mean) is closed and Internet Archive's [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://gtag.gtagaming.com/mods/53-stream-ini-extender-07/) hasn't archived the download. I have a local backup - how should I share the file?

Comment: Don't worry about it. Your question has an answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill: I used my question more as an example.

Comment: It is never mandatory. You should try and include enough information in the question so that it is self-contained and doesn't require access to external resources (apart from images, which should be hosted on i,stack.imgur.com)

Comment: Let's not dismiss the question so fast.  For example, in many questions that involve system problems, people request various logs or dumps to diagnose the issue.  These are typically long and would detract from the question if embedded.  The site hosts images at imgur, but we probably don't want to encourage people using steganography to upload files embedded in images.

Comment: These type of questions isn't about the literal solution in most cases but the process to determine the cause.  As answer author's we should do our best to describe the process to determine the cause.  This way future similar questions can be answered by the same process and we don't have to worry about dozens of questions that require windbg analysis